# Replacement front wheel for Fastroad SL-1 2019

Tags: wheels

I'm looking for a replacement front wheel for a Giant Fastroad SL-1 from 2019.

I'd like to replace it with the same wheel or something with similar specs if possible.

The wheel is labelled as a SR2-Disc, has 28 spokes and is running a 700 x 28 tyre. I'm not sure about the depth. Some other markings on the wheel are ETRTO 622x17 .

I'm running with inner tubes so tubeless isn't a requirement for me. I'd definitely like to avoid downgrading any other specs though.

LBS who retail Giant thought that this part isn't sold as a replacement, and that a generic wheel won't come in a spoke count that low.

Could I get an an idea of what similar wheels I could use or how to get the same wheel as a replacement? I'm a bit lost.

Thanks in advance!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVHJx.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3VXZ.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrUbD.jpg

Comment: Was your old wheel damaged somehow ?   If it failed then you might prefer to get a different brand of wheel instead.

Answer (score 2):

Giant tends to use its own branded rather than 'name brand' components.

If you bike store thinks they cannot get a replacement wheel from Giant I'd try contacting [Giant customer support](https://www.giant-bicycles.com/us/contact) yourself. It seems unlikely that Giant cannot provide a replacement wheel for a recent bike model.

If you cannot obtain a replacement Giant wheel, obtaining a replacement that is identical in specifications and similar in appearance should be easy. 28 spoke front wheels certainly are available (and that's not a particularly low spoke count). 'ETRTO 622x17' is the specification for rim diameter and internal width in millimeters. 622mm diameter wheels are also known as '700c'. I think from the [FastRoad SL-1 webpage](https://www.giant-bicycles.com/us/fastroad-sl-1-2019) the hubs are quick release rather than through-axle. The other specification needed is whether you have 6-bolt brake rotor mount or Shimano center-lock.